# Why isn't my function reaching this point?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, promise

I've been stuck for an hour trying to figure this out. I have a function that now looks like

```
myfunction()
{
    console.log("myfunction called");//TEST
    Axios.post('someurl/' + id)
        .then(response =>
        {
            console.log("We're in the .then ...");//TEST
            onGoodRequest(response.data, response);
        })
        .catch(response =>
        {
            console.log("We're in the .catch ...");//TEST
            this.setState({ curUploadState: uploadStates.SHOWSTOPPER });
        });
    console.log("We're here now ...");//TEST
}
```

which I call inside my React component and for some reason it's getting stuck. There are no JavaScript errors in the console and the only thing I see is

```
myfunction called
```

So what could possibly be going on? I even did

```
    var x = Axios.post('someurl/' + id)
                .then(response =>
                {
                    console.log("We're in the .then ...");
                    onGoodRequest(response.data, response);
                })
                .catch(response =>
                {
                    console.log("We're in the .catch ...");
                    this.setState({ curUploadState: uploadStates.SHOWSTOPPER });
                });
    console.log(x);
    console.log("We're here now ...");
```

and nothing logged.

Comment: Have you tried opening the network tab in chrome and seeing what it says after the post?

Comment: @NaderDabit No request even happens. It's so strange.

Comment: put more source code, how did you import axios?

Comment: Is `Axios` accessible to `myfunction`? If Reactjs is consuming errors you may need to set a break point and debug

Comment: arrow functions have implicit returns, so if your curly braces are on the next line after the => in your actual code, that will early return. If so the answer below is correct, despite someone down voting it.

Comment: `myfunction() { ... }` is neither a function declaration nor a function expression. Are you sure you aren't getting a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are returning nothing because your arrow function is on the line above the curly braces. Move the curly braces up a line:

```
myfunction()
{
    console.log("myfunction called");//TEST
    Axios.post('someurl/' + id)
        .then(response => {
            console.log("We're in the .then ...");//TEST
            onGoodRequest(response.data, response);
        })
        .catch(response => {
            console.log("We're in the .catch ...");//TEST
            this.setState({ curUploadState: uploadStates.SHOWSTOPPER });
        });
    console.log("We're here now ...");//TEST
}
```

`=>` is basically an implicit return.